# get maximum date/time from different id's

Tags: mysql, sql

TABLE 1

```
id  time                  user
1   2016-12-19 13:57:00   32
1   2016-12-19 14:57:00   32
1   2016-12-24 09:57:00   654
2   2017-02-17 10:54:00   654
2   2017-02-17 16:04:00   654
2   2017-02-23 00:54:00   1001
```

TABLE 2

```
user  status
32    admin
654   admin
1001  new
```

I want to get maximum `time` for each `id` from "TABLE 1" and match `status` from TABLE 2 if it is new.

The important thing is how to get maximum `time` from each `id` ?

Result should be

```
id  time                  status
2   2017-02-23 00:54:00   new
```

Comment: SELECT MAX(time) FROM table1 WHERE id = 1

Answer (score 0):

Just join two table with `user`, then group by `id` with `max` function:

```
select tbl1.id, max(tbl1.`time`) as `time`, tbl2.`status`
from tbl1
join tbl2 on tbl1.user = tbl2.user
where tbl2.`status` = 'new'
group by tbl1.id
```

See [**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/260e8/1) here.

Answer (score 0):

Answering

> The important thing is how to get maximum time from each id ?

part of your query.

```
Select id,max(time)
From Table1 
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the maximum row from the first table in various ways.  Here is one:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.time = (select max(tt1.time) from t1 tt1 where tt1.id = t1.id);
```

Then, you can extend this for the columns from `table2`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.user = t2.user
where t1.time = (select max(tt1.time) from t1 tt1 where tt1.id = t1.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo website: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/260e8/6

table

```
VALUES
(1, '2016-12-19 13:57:00', 32),
(1, '2016-12-19 14:57:00', 32),
(1, '2016-12-24 09:57:00', 654),
```

When I run the script as

`Select user,max(time)
From tbl1 
where id = '1'`

OUTPUT
max(time) = 2016-12-24 09:57:00

user = 32 // WRONG should be 654 !!!

How can I get the final user from max(time) ?